# C++ Memory Ordering Consistency

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, garbage-collection

Let's say I have the following code:

```
void* p0 = nullptr;
void* p1 = alloc_some_data();
void f1() {
    p0 = p1;
    p1 = nullptr;
}
```

Suppose `f1` is run on thread 1. Is it possible that (leaving the code as it is) another thread may at some point see `p0` and `p1` as `nullptr` (if compiler or hardware reorders instructions such as the second assignment happens before the first)?

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to implement a garbage collector and I want to know if I need to access pointers from the GC thread using atomic instructions (`std::atomic`). There's no problem if the GC thread sees `p0 == p1 == alloc_some_data()` but there will be problems if the GC thread sees `p0 == p1 == nullptr` because then it will report the data previously in p1 as unreachable when it's clearly is reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  While not necessarily likely, it is entirely possible because those operations are not atomic.

One (of a few possible scenarios) is this:

```
Thread 2: Get value of p0 (null)

Thread 1: Get value of p1 (non-null)
          p0 = p1
          p1 = nullptr

Thread 2: Get value of p1 (null)
```

You need to use some form of access control (*ie* a mutex).

Comment: From my understanding, the advantage of tracing gc over ref counting is avoiding locks (in refs increments). If each reference update in a mutator thread needs a mutex lock, then where's the performance gain over ref counting? The tracing gc approach then bloats the code path with locks just like ref counting methods (in the mutator threads), right? Is it possible to write a tracing gc where the mutator threads can update a reference with a simple MOV instruction? Can anyone point me to one direction (an article or a book...)?

Comment: I don't know enough about garbage collection to comment.  Personally, I like reference-counting because memory is released as soon as possible.  Some operating systems provide atomic increment and decrement instructions that are much faster than using mutexes.  In such cases, reference-counting wins.  If you are using Windows/Visual Studio, you might want to have a look at the Microsoft-specific `volatile` semantics.

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho: I am not too familiar with GC either, but many non-reference counting GC are *stop-the-world* GC: the environment will stop all threads, perform GC (possibly relocating objects and updating pointers) and then let all threads continue.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. "Because these operations are not atomic" just means that you might observe intermediate results. However, the question is about reordering. These two concepts are orthogonal. E.g. it's entirely legal to reorder two atomic writes. In that case you'll never see half a write, but you may see the second write before the first.

Comment: Atomics in C++ 2011 optionally specify a memory order. The default memory order (`std::memory_order_seq_cst`) seems to introduce fairly strong ordering. Of course, the above didn't mention any details but this seems to be a good reason to assume the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

If you read an object in one thread which is written by another thread without synchronization you have a data race. This clearly implies that your garbage collector will need to read the values using some sort of synchronization. With respect to your original question: there is nothing in your code indicating that the write to `p0` becomes visible prior to the write of `p1`, i.e., another thread can, indeed, see both to be null. This is independent of the synchronization primitives used to communicate with another thread: there is no ordering between these two writes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes but it's compiler and CPU dependent. I think you also need to make `p0` and `p1` volatile. To stop reordering you can use the `_mm_sfence` and `_mm_lfence` instrinsics (for x86/x64)

Comment: Making objects `volatile` is entirely irrelevant with respect to threading in C++ 2011. Also, C++ 2011 has standardized functions to introduce fences (however, I can't comment on how to use them because I haven't tried using them).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Have you a link to support the lack of need for volatile? How does the compiler know not to cache a read?

Comment: As far as I understand, `volatile` is required when hardware/interrupts can alter the memory.  That is not the case here.  Microsoft have added their own semantics to `volatile` which may be what you're thinking about, but that is not ISO-conformant.

Comment: @James: Sure: ISO/IEC 14882:2011 1.10 [intro.multithread], especially paragraph 5. The only mention in 1.10 of `volatile` is is in paragraph 24 which says that a thread may serve a purpose in some observable way, one of which happens to write a `volatile` object. In the context were `volatile` is referenced, it is **not** in any relation with synchronization (the bullet point after the mention of `volatile` is the one relating to synchronization). The meaning of `volatile` in C++ has nothing to do at all with thread synchronization. It is used with hardware changing memory mapped values.

Comment: NO, NO, NO: `volatile` has **never** been a portable solution to data races.